# Handling errors with uxiframe component

Tags: extjs, extjs5

From grid data my app produces a report with fpdf that is displayed on a tab with the uxiframe component. 
Works well.

However, I need to deal with the errors.

uxiframe suport a load method, but it does not have any success or failure method or success property.

Assuming the following response is sent by the server:

```
{msg: "Problem...", success: false}
```

And with a button I add a new tab with uxiframe

```
 var newTab = mainPanel.add({
     xtype: 'uxiframe',
     closable: true,
     title: 'PDF report',
     src: 'php/fpdreport.php,
     listeners:{
          load: function(operation){
                 console.log(operation);
          }
     }
  });
```

Will there be some way to display the message "Problem ..." ?

EDITED:

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2bj7

Pdf for test: 'https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/executive-dashboard/resources/reports/Q42013Report.pdf'

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below:-

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    requires: ['Ext.ux.IFrame'],
    launch: function () {

        var panel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'uxiframe',
                closable: true,
                title: 'PDF report',
                loader: {
                    url: 'php/fpdreport.php',
                    autoLoad: true,
                    callback: function (ths, success, response, options) {
                        console.log(response);
                        panel.setHtml(response.statusText);
                    }
                }
            }]
        });

    }
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks imEnCoded, but this does not work; try with a fiddle and the pdf added to my post,

Comment: Hello josei, I have already tried with fiddle and here is it https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2bju

Comment: Hello imEnCoded. Try with the pdf for test in my post. Callback function works ok with loader, but does not load the uxiframe component or the pdf document.